# How to set a virtualbox differencing disk to immutable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

i have a shared disk in virtualbox (called multi-attached in gui) i want to keep it shared but make vm disk sharing it immutable after i've made some changes to it is this possible in virtualbox?

Here's a better example (hopefully) of what i want to do

```
             -> VM1  Differencing Disk -> VM1 Immutable Disk
            |
Shared Disk  -> VM2 Differencing Disk
            |
            ...
```

I've tried setting the VM1 drive located under the snapeshot directory to immutable using both `vboxmanage modifyhd <UUID>.vdi settype immutable` and `vboxmanage modifyhd <UUID>.vdi --type immutable` but i get the error below

```
VBoxManage: error: Cannot change the type of medium '<VM PATH>/Snapshots/<UUID>.vdi' because it is a differencing medium
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "COMSETTER(Type)(enmMediumType)" at line 691 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
```

I've also tried `vboxmanage modifyhd <UUID> --autoreset on` however this resets the disk to the state of the shared disk instead of the shared disk with changes i made before setting autoreset to on.

If it matters i'm using Virtualbox 5.1.22 on Ubuntu 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this first make your changes to the initial differencing disk then snapshot the VM and use the snapshots disk uuid in `vboxmanage modifyhd <UUID> --autoreset on`, now on start up of the VM it will automatically reset the disk to the state when the snapshot was taken.